# how to pass query inside a add on success listner

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

[image: databse structure]

I want to pass a query inside a addOnSuccessListener

i have tried to work on this but i'm not getting expected results

```
   db.collection("Buildings").get()
    .addOnSuccessListener(new                                          

       OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
       @Override
       public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot  queryDocumentSnapshots) {
        if (!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()){
            progressDialog.setTitle("Opening Buildings. Please Wait..");
            progressDialog.show();
            List<DocumentSnapshot> list =  queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments();

            for (DocumentSnapshot d:list){
                Building b = d.toObject(Building.class);
                b.setId(d.getId());
                buildingList.add(b);
            }
            progressDialog.hide();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
});
```

Output is coming from above code is all the list of buildings
i want to display only some of them

Comment: You say you want to display only some of them, which one of them? Please add your database structure and indicate which one of the buildings you want to get.

Comment: i want to display them according to there id and i have given id to each of them like 1,2,3,4,5 and all

Comment: buildingId "A"
buildingaddress "ABC"
buildingname "XYZ"
mchnumber "123"
noofflats "10"
ownername "Guest"
ptinumber "1100879969"

Comment: Instead of describing how you database looks like, please add a screenshot of it.

Comment: i have added it on the top of my post please check it

Comment: You say you want to display only some of them, which one of them? What is the condition you want to use for those buildings?

Comment: i have solved that query thank you for your time sir i got the solution from my firend